# What is the difference between ${var} and {$var} in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have seen some code in PHP use this expression `${variable}`, so; what is this? and when to use it? and what is the difference between `${var}` and `{$var}` ?

Comment: @Rafael, Yes I am pretty sure.

Comment: I deleted it because I couln't edit on my connection. I remember seeing it now but only inside strings. I think the example on the refered answer is quite elaborated though. (I knew some of the cases but not that many)